# Invalid literal for float in k nearest neighbor

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am having the hardest time figuring out why i am getting this error. I have searched a lot but unable to fine any solution

```
import numpy as np
import warnings
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

def k_nearest_neighbors(data, predict, k=3):
if len(data) >= k:
    warnings.warn('K is set to a value less than total voting groups!')
distances = []
for group in data:
    for features in data[group]:
        euclidean_distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(features)-
np.array(predict))
        distances.append([euclidean_distance,group])
votes = [i[1] for i in sorted(distances)[:k]]
vote_result = Counter(votes).most_common(1)[0][0]
return vote_result

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
df.replace('?',-99999, inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)
full_data = df.astype(float).values.tolist()

print(full_data)
```

After running. it gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Jazab\Machine Learning\Lec18(Testing K Neatest Nerighbors 
Classifier)\Lec18(Testing K Neatest Nerighbors 
Classifier)\Lec18_Testing_K_Neatest_Nerighbors_Classifier_.py", line 25, in 
<module>
full_data = df.astype(float).values.tolist()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 91, in 
wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3299, in 
astype
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3224, in 
astype
return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3091, in 
apply
applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 471, in 
astype
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 521, in 
_astype
values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 636, 
in astype_nansafe
return arr.astype(dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3) <-----Reappears in Group 8 as:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

if i remove `astype(float)` program run fine
What should i need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

There are bad data (`3)`), so need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) because need processes all columns.

Non numeric are converted to `NaN`s, which are replaced by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to some scalar, e.g. `0`:

```
full_data = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).values.tolist()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,7], 'B':['3)',4,5]})
print (df)
   A   B
0  1  3)
1  2   4
2  7   5

full_data = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).values.tolist()
print (full_data)
[[1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 4.0], [7.0, 5.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `3)` as an entry in your CSV file, and Pandas is complaining because it can't cast it to a float because of the `)`.

Comment: my CSV have records of patients

Comment: Maybe show an example of the file, in your question. Anyway, I think jezrael's answer is what you need if you have no control over the source data.